# When inserting a row in between previously auto-generated formulas, how to fill certain columns with those formulas?

Tags: google-sheets

My Google Sheet has a text header, and then a few columns (let's say F and I) have a formula in them.
So as an example row 1 is all text, and row 2 would have `=LEFT(H2,4)&" "&MID(H2,5,6)`. This was dragged down (auto filled) below so row 3 has `H3` in the formula etc. all the way to say 100.

If I go insert a row at 50, is there a way for it to automatically fill in the formula  `H50`.  (Currently when I insert row, all the cells are blank).

Two 'test case' formulas:

`=LEFT(H2,4)&" "&MID(H2,5,6)&"!"`

`=IF (ISBLANK(H2),"", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (MOD(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(H2))&H2,ROW($1:$31),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$31),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(H2))&H2,ROW($1:$31),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$31),2)+1),10)),10)=0), "✔", "❌")), 1, 1))`

(This formula is from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1589622/excel-formula-to-test-if-15-or-16-digit-number-is-a-valid-credit-card-and-return) - to test out in your own spreadsheet, H simply needs any valid credit card number such as 343280696646912 )

Comment: I respectfully suggest that this question is no longer a "general" question about repeating a simple formula in every row. Instead, the real "problem" is your credit card formula, and how to adapt/rewrite this so that he automatically repeats in every row. You should write a new question about this; I suggest that you ask the question on StackOverflow (not WebApps) because it has a much bigger group of volunteers which increases the odds of getting an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `=arrayformula(LEFT(H2:H100,4)&" "&MID(H2:H100,5,6))` in the cell B2.

This will automatically populate cells "B2:B100" with the formula. If you insert a new row, the cell in Column B will populate with the formula.

Comment: Thank you, this is working great for the simple formula, but I've added a very complex formula above that uses array_constrain and arrayformula already.  Wrapping it in ArrayFormula: `=ARRAYFORMULA( IF (ISBLANK(H2:H1000),"", ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF( (MOD(SUM(INT(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(H2:H1000))&H2:H1000,ROW($1:$31),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$31),2)+1)/10)+MOD(MID(REPT("0",20-LEN(H2:H1000))&H2:H1000,ROW($1:$31),1)*(MOD(ROW($1:$31),2)+1),10)),10)=0), "✔", "❌")), 1, 1)))`  gives Error `Function REPT parameter 2 value is negative. It should be positive or zero.`

Comment: If you are using this complex formula based on Arrayformula, why didn’t you just apply arrayformula to your “simple” formula. In any event, I suggest that you look to move the “if is blank” (or an equivalent statement) to within your own formula rather than add an additional layer of arrayformula.

Comment: Sorry can you please elaborate? (Potentially with examples, once I use array constrain and formula I get confused).  My goal is to simply get the ✔ or ❌ at the end, but only if the cell has data, otherwise blank.